# Eclipse IDE not resolving my src classnames

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Seemingly out of the blue (although I think it happened inexplicably after an ant build) my Eclipse IDE stopped resolving the Java class names of those I have created inside my project, giving me a nice list of red 'x's in my package explorer.

I'm not sure how or why this happened, and I'm having a hard time getting Eclipse to see them again. Under project properties the source tab in Java Build Path references is src dir as you would expect. In comparison the Referenced Libraries have all the jars I use and those are not giving any issue. How could I resolve it?

Comment: Maybe the project preferences were mixed up. Anyway, I would save everything and then restart Eclipse.

Comment: Have you checked your build path ?

Comment: have you tried recreating the workspace. eclipse seems to "just do" these kind of things, and if other things don't help, recreating the workspace usually does.

Comment: Hmm. I had one additional warning about 'JRE_LIB' being deprecated, use the system JRE instead. So I added that lib and suddenly the references are 'visible' again. Maybe that recreates the workspace as part of adding the new lib? For future ref how would I rebuild the workspace manually myself?

Comment: ah, see now, under Project clean... thanks

Answer (score 1):

1)Right Click on Project , navigate to **Build Path** and then click **Configure Build Path**

2)Now click on tab **Sources** , there you have to verify that the programs under the folder src , is stated in the Sources tab correctly.

*Lets say my project name is EmpService , and my programs are in src folder (forget about package , in fact package must be under src) , then the tab would be showing like this*-

> EmpService/src/

Regards

Anshul

Comment: As I stated in my question, my build path sources are configured as you would expect.